# Vietnam e-visa with one nationality but two valid passports

Tags: visas, passports, vietnam

There are questions in the Vietnam e-visa application form asking about multiple nationalities and multiple passports.

I'm a non-dual citizen of Hungary but I have two valid passports, both issued by Hungary. Will there be any confusion about this? Many countries don't allow more than one valid passport at a time and thus such a combination of answers could potentially look contradictory.

What's the reason they want to know about other passports anyway? Does anybody have any related experience?

Comment: At a minimum, you'd probably want to be sure to use the same passport (number) at _all_ times for this trip to Vietnam. Just to make your life easier.

Comment: @FreeMan What do you mean? I will enter once and exit once. Do you mean accommodation? Also, do you think it can be a problem that I'm switching passports and my exit stamp from Malaysia is not in the passport I'll enter Vietnam on but in the other one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I too have two passports issued by the same country (France), and have run once in a minor hiccup related to this. I was at Malaysia Immigration in KLIA, and the officer asked me whether I had another passport, number XXXXXX. I said yes indeed. She then went all pissy about how I shouldn't do that, and should always use the same passport when coming to Malaysia. She looked very displeased, although I still can't figure out why.

So I told her my other passport was with the Chinese consulate for a visa application (can't remember whether that was the case or not, but that's actually the reason France issues 2 passports to people who ask, so we can do exactly this). She still wasn't pleased about that and made more noises, then said something about "wait until you get your passport back before coming," yada yada.

This never happened again, either in Malaysia or elsewhere, so I suspect I was "lucky" enough to encounter a very bureaucratic officer that day. But it does seem that some countries want to keep tabs on everything related to you passports.

The part about dual (or more) citizenships is often related to political issues – countries they may be at odds with, for example. Like India demands to know whether you're Pakistani in any form or shape. Or Singapore wanting to know whether you were Malaysian at any time, even if you show up with say a US passport. Or of course whether you are Singaporean and something else (which is illegal). And since countries like yours and mine that issue 2 passports are rare, I believe that the expression "2 or more passports" for most people means "2 or more citizenships".

Comment: Have you ever entered Vietnam while switching passports (exit the previous country on one passport and enter Vietnam on another)?

Comment: @oddin As far as I can remember, not Vietnam, no. Every time I entered Vietnam it was from HK, which doesn't stamp passports (especially those of residents) and never did the Immigration officer ask about stamps.

Answer (score 8):

> Many countries don't allow more than one valid passport at a time

And many do.  In fact, while the proportion of individuals holding more than one valid passport from the same country is probably very small indeed, the proportion of countries offering multiple passports is probably not very small.  For example, [a Lonely Planet article](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/articles/countries-that-issue-multiple-passports) mentions 23, not counting two that are mentioned for issuing concurrent personal and diplomatic passports, which is another matter entirely and probably common.

> Will there be any confusion about this?

Probably not.  While people with multiple passports from the same country are likely to be a fairly small proportion of the population, they're going to be among the most prolific travelers, so Vietnam surely will have encountered this situation before.

> What's the reason they want to know about other passports anyway?

To make it easier to link any past or future travel records linked to those passorts.  Yes, they can do that by comparing your name and your date and place of birth, but they can be that much more confident in the accuracy of the match if they have an explicit link between the document numbers.